# How to add a day onto a date parsed string?

Tags: groovy

I am trying to do a simple add a day to my substring text that i've parsed into a date but it is not displaying correctly.

Below is the code:

```
def dateTimeDate = Date.parse("yyyy-mm-dd", textfromjson.substring(0,10)).format("yyyy-mm-dd")
def futureDateTimeDate = dateTimeDate + 1
```

When I do two logs for both defs, the original date and the future date which I want to be next day, I receive this output:

logs:

```
log.warn dateTimeDate
log.error futureDateTimeDate
```

output:

```
2018-02-23
2018-02-231
```

How can I get this to work so that it outputs: `2018-02-24` and not `2018-02-231`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're parsing a String into a Date and then formatting it back into a String. Add to the Date object, not the String object.

```
def dateTimeDate = Date.parse("yyyy-mm-dd", textfromjson.substring(0,10))
def futureDateTimeDate = dateTimeDate + 1

log.warn dateTimeDate.format("yyyy-MM-dd")
log.error futureDateTimeDate.format("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Also note that you probably want to be using `MM` (month in year) not `mm` (minute in hour).

Answer (score 2):

The answers posted already correctly point out that the date value needs to be incremented before it's formatted back into a String.

To this, I would like to add that if you're on Java 8 you can use its new Date/Time API as an alternative to java.util.Date, which can be problematic (even apart from mixing up 'm' and 'M' in format strings).

```
import java.time.*
def future = LocalDate.parse(textfromjson.substring(0,10)) + Period.ofDays(1)
```